# Assign string based on integer

Tags: php

I have a list of values eg. `1 - 100`, what I need to do is the following:
There are values relating to these number, so `1 = pink, 2 = blue, 3 = grey, etc.` when it gets to `12 = green`, it has to start over, so then 13 would be pink again, and the whole sequence is restarted.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. All coding done in PHP.

Comment: Show us your code please..!!

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: use the modulo operator (`%`).

Comment: You're looking for modulo operator - http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple task for `modulo` operator and `switch`.

```
<?php

$number = 98;

switch ($number % 12) {
    case 1:
        $color: pink;
        break;

    case 2:
        $color: blue;
        break;

    ...
}

echo $color;

?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the modulo and a array of colors.

```
<?php

$number = 13;
$colors = ['pink',   'blue',   'grey',
           'yellow', 'red',    'green',
           'white',  'black',  'purple',
           'brown',  'orange', 'ocean'];

// number-1 if you want the pink color
echo $colors[($number-1) % count($colors)];
```

Comment: Clean and elegant solution. I would replace `12` with `count($colors)`

Comment: @tkovs: it's cleaner than my switch if we need just one action. +1

Comment: @cbaconnier yeah, count($colors) is more readable, ty.